# Start ubuntu 13.04 from preinstalled window 8

Tags: 13.04, boot, windows-8

I have a Dell inspiron 1012 mini laptop. It came with window 8 preinstalled. I installed ubutu 13.04 from usb but the problem is that at boot time there is no sign of grub loader and i can't see any list of operating system so that i can select ubuntu. By default window 8 i loaded. I have window 8 installed in my C drive and ubuntu in D drive as well as boot loader for ubuntu is also in D. At the time of installation there were 3 options : first was replace window 8 with ubuntu ,second was erase all & third was something else and i installed ubuntu using 3rd option I searched a lot on net but didn't find a correct solution for me. Please help me to get rid of this situation. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Ubuntu` is already installed you may want to re-install the `grub loader`. [Link Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

You can also fix it using [Easy BCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) by creating `dual boot menu`.